# Term order when saving a new taxonomy term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

By default when you're saving a new taxonomy term it's placed by the alphabetical order, how to make newly added terms to appear below the existed terms? Or even highlight it? Because i have like 200 terms and it's hard to manage it when you're adding a new term.

Comment: I also find this annoying. I enter all of my terms in a specific order and then Drupal puts them all in alphabetical order! However if I was adding 200 terms I would use something like [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv).

Comment: Any suggestions except CSV export/import? :) I've tried taxonomy manager module but it's the same lol as standard one. Just the improved UI.

Comment: Write a custom script to programmatically create all of the terms.

Comment: Well, that's will be time consuming. No other alternatives like taxonomy manager?

Comment: Not that I've aware of. But there may be...

Answer (score 1):

while I am not aware of a solution that will get you this exactly behavior without spending a bunch of time on a unique setup, there maybe a simple workaround for you to quickly identify the new term and move it to whereever it belongs to.

but first of, the definition or new terms being sorted alphabetically is not entirely true. by default, newly added taxonomy terms have a Weight of '0'.
this Weight value serves as the first sort criteria: terms with a higher Weight value will be further down, as will terms with a lower Weight value (can be negative too) appear further up in the list.
only when multiple terms share the same Weight value, they further get sorted alphabetically.

you can see the exact Weight value for every term by clicking *Show row weights* just above the top right-hand corner of the table.

so if you have a taxonomy vocabulary where all terms have a Weight of -1 and below, newly added terms will be found at the very bottom of the list.

while this will put new terms to the very end of a list, setting up a list this way may be rather tedious, as you might run out of negative numbers or simply because managing 200+ entries this way can  be a pain in the butt. instead, there is another approach I find myself using most of the time:

there are two View Modes managing Weights: one enables you to manually define a Weight value via a select list (the 'show row weights' mode mentioned above), and the other one lets you sort individual terms via dragging and dropping by clicking on the cross/drag cursor on the very left of each term. when you manually define a term order by dragging and dropping (dont forget to hit *Save*!), every term will be given a unite Weight value starting by 0.

 this means only the very first term will have a Weight of 0. the second term will have a Weight of 1, the third gets a Weight of 2 and so forth.

when you now add a new term, it will be assigned the weight of 0 as well, placing it as either the very **first or second term** in the list. this will enable you to find it immediately and place it wherever you need it to be.

if you find yourself wanting to place that new term at the very bottom, dragging it all the way down can be tedious as well, so a quicker way now would be to enable *Show row weights* again, just pick the lowest value and hit Save.

again, maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for, depending on whether you actually care about the order they are listed, or just want to identify the newest entry.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but if i was managing it - it would be no problem, but i have a content manager which is uncomfortable to do this in such way. I am trying to make it highlighting with jQuery now.